# Output formatting in pandas describe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, describe

I have some problems with formatting describe table from pandas.
I would love to have 2 decimals precision in every column, but in last I need to have 1.11e11 format. I have tried applying

```
data.styles.format({"last_column": "{:.2E}"})
```

, but it does not seem to work for me, still the same result as can be seen below.

Things like: pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.2E}'.format)
is applied pandas-wide, which is not what I want to do.

```
print(data.describe(percentiles=[],).fillna("-.--").round(2))
count           1               1               1             1        1               1
mean         1.43             0.4           34.58          0.07     0.71     1.12877e+08
std          -.--            -.--            -.--          -.--     -.--            -.--
min          1.43             0.4           34.58          0.07     0.71     1.12877e+08
50%          1.43             0.4           34.58          0.07     0.71     1.12877e+08
max          1.43             0.4           34.58          0.07     0.71     1.12877e+08
```

I would like to evade if tabulate, or any other tabular tool if possible, would like to solve this on level of pandas.

Does anyone please have a solution?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this:-

```
pd.set_option('precision',2)
```

and if you want to `reset` it back to original form i.e its `default value` then use this:-

```
pd.reset_option('precision')
```